# Can't see changes after deploying ssrs report ax2012

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have made some changes in SSRS Report in VS 14 and deployed it to AX2012 R3 CU9, but still I can't see the changes. I even tried to stop AOS, delete XppiL folder, restart AOS and made a complete CIL compilation. Still not working.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Have you tried to build & deploy report inside Visual Studio (as administrator)?

Comment: Yes, I did. Usually, that's the way which works for me.

Comment: Has the report more than one design? If so, are you sure the modified design is used (check print management)?

Comment: Yes, it has more than one design, but not, I'm positively sure that I'm modifying the right one (the settled in Print management). I can see it even debugging. I think is some kind of problem with caché, or maybe there could be some issue with two report servers in the same machine?

Comment: Try to delete the report in the web Interface of the report server and then deploy the report from AX.

Comment: Restart the reporting service :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you also clicked on Tools->Caches->Refresh Report Server?

Try also the following:
The Standard AX Configuration should Point to the AX you try to deploy the Report. The Standard AX Configuration ist the configuration that is shown, if you open the Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 Configuration Utility.
Also try to refresh the WCF Configuration by clicking on Refresh Configuration in the Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 Configuration.

Is there more then one Report Server running on that Server? If so you should read this:
This article is about having the right *.axc file pointing to the right AOS in the SSRS Setup. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh389774.aspx

And the last tipp:
In the AIF Ports try to stop and start the Inbound-BI Servide Port.

I hope that one of these helps.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:

> 1. if you are on R3, you have the Tools -> Caches -> Refresh report server;
> 2. also, do a Tools -> Caches -> Refresh elements and Tools -> Caches -> Refresh dictionary;
> 3. if you have an AOT query, you can do a Restore on the query;
> 4. open the report in Visual Studio, and perform a Refresh on your dataset in the Datasets node;
> 5. also in Visual Studio perform a rebuild and a deploy of the report;
> 6. before step 5. you can check that the parameters you have for your report are the proper ones (if you've changed the data contract or the
>      query);
> 7. depending on the decision to load the last values (controller.parmLoadFromSysLastValue) you want to do a Reset usage
>      data;
> 8. and last but not least, you want to do a Restore and then also a Deploy element on the report in the AOT.

If your still facing the issue then finally restart your SQL Server Reporting Services in service and run the report.

OR

> sometimes you need to delete the report in the report document folder,
>   then deploy again to get the latest version published. After that
>   restart the SSRS service instance.

I hope that one of these helps.

For more information you can visit: [SSRS Report](https://360dynamics.blogspot.com/2017/10/ssrs-report-cant-see-changes-after.html)